# cannot pass value from app component to id attribute in index.html in angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular5

I have angular5 application which I want to enable or disable id attribute value of index.html file in the project. I'm passing value to index.html from app.component.ts file.
first of all Is it possible to pass value to index.html file from app component.

I wrap up  in a div with attribute "id". so that I can pass a value to id attribute. make id attribute as directive. (don't know this is possible)

app.component.ts file

```
toggleMindsphereOSBar() {
    return this.exp = this.globalService.getConfig().MINDSPHERE_OS_BAR ? '_mdspcontent': null;
  }
```

index.html file

```html
<body class="blue-grey lighten-5">
  <div [id]="toggleMindsphereOSBar()">
      <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
```

I can get the value of this.exp variable which I wanted. but, when I inspected index.html file in browser that value not injected to the dom.
it showing [id]="toggleMindsphereOSBar() as it is.

[image]

can anyone give me a insight how to resolve this or what I have done wrong here.
thanks

Comment: I'm expert with angular but tried to reproduce your issue but I couldn't: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvjun5

Comment: @MoshFeu Is it possible to pass value from app component to index.html file ? because in angular we can pass data between components , right ?

Comment: index.html is not the template of the component so I guess not..